# angularjs clear history when view loaded

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way of clearing the history that Angular JS stores when a particular view is loaded through the `routeProvider`?

I am creating a public installation using angular and the history is going to build up a lot so I want to clear it when the home page is loaded.

Answer (score 10):

in your Controller inject $scope and $location.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
  //view loaded do some stuff.
    $location.replace(); //clear last history route
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the controller I added a function to change the view:

```
$scope.changeView = function(view) {
    $location.path(view);
    $location.replace();
}
```

Then within the view I added an ng-click to call this function:

```
<div ng-click="changeView('/app/new_view')">
```

From the angular Docs $location.replace() method is used to replace the topmost view in the history stack, instead of adding a new one.

> There is a special **`replace`** method which can be used to tell the $location service that the next time the $location service is synced with the browser, the last history record should be replaced instead of creating a new one.

Reference:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: That is not what this code does. Instead, it loads the new view and adds it to history, replacing the last element in the history.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(var a=0; a < $rootScope.$viewHistory.histories.root.stack.length; a++ ){
         console.log(" for history remove " + a );
         delete $rootScope.$viewHistory.histories.root.stack[a];
     }
```

Comment: Code is good, but a plain-English explanation can't hurt. See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: `$rootScope.$viewHistory` is undefined. It is something which you are adding to `$rootScope` or angular provides it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dummyState = {app: 'resto'};

// set up history state
if (!$window.history.state) {
  $window.history.pushState(dummyState, '');
}

// when history back
$window.onpopstate = function() {
  console.log('window.onpopstate:url=', $window.location.href);
  console.log('window.onpopstate:history.state=', $window.history.state);

  // repopulate history state so we get the popstate event again
  $window.history.pushState(dummyState, '');
};
```