# Disabling AngularJS $http cache

Tags: angularjs, http, caching

I'm trying to disable the cache in my AngularJS app, but it isn't working with the following code:

```
$http.get("myurl",{cache:false})
```

When I use `"myurl&random="+Math.random()`, the cache is disabled; but, I'd like a different approach.

Comment: This is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098430/angular-ie-caching-issue-for-http).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular IE Caching issue for $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098430/angular-ie-caching-issue-for-http)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098430/angular-ie-caching-issue-for-http).

Pasting code snippet from the link for your reference.

```
myModule.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    //initialize get if not there
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};    
    }    

    // Answer edited to include suggestions from comments
    // because previous version of code introduced browser-related errors

    //disable IE ajax request caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT';
    // extra
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
}]);
```

Comment: I recommend not using Pragma one. it's not a standard (apparently) and may cause problems with Cross Origin requests. Just finished a 2 hour debug session with friends to understand that was the cause of the problem.

Comment: @guymograbi What do you recommend then?

Comment: @Schoof does the problem still occur if you simply remove Pragma?

Comment: on chrome back button I use to get json bcoz of the same URL, from the above code I solved it Thank you!!

Answer (score 13):

Here is what I did, simply change it to

```
 $http.get("myurl",{headers:{'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
  $state(' 'app.name', {
 url: '/name',
cache: false,
 controller:'MainCtrl',
 templateUrl:'templates/name.html'
 })
```

Comment: not sure how this answer applies.   The question is about http get. not templates.

Answer (score -1):

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {controller: 'MyCtrl', templateUrl: '/eshop/myConfig'})
})

.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $templateCache) {
    $templateCache.remove('/eshop/myConfig');
    // or
    $templateCache.removeAll();
});
```

i didn't test it.i found something in this url.Have a look at this
[Angularjs - how to clear $routeProvider's caches of templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284976/angularjs-how-to-clear-routeproviders-caches-of-templateurl)